# Navigation drop-down menu not working properly in flexbox container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make a full-width navigation with css dropdown.

It works all fine, but I have one concern: Because the navigation must be full width, all items must have the same `width` as each other. So, what I did was divided the `width: 100%` by all `li`'s. For now this is fine but if I have to add another item I have to calculate the `width` of the items again.

What I would like is to use `flexbox`, so if I add another item it will auto align the items on the whole `width` of the `ul`. But when I tried to do that, it doesn't turn out how I would like. It shows the whole `ul` below it when hovering on a item.

For now it doesn't have to be responsive.

Below my code I've added a jsfiddle with the `flexbox` what will show what is wrong.

```css
ul.nav-dropdown {
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: #3f3f3f !important;
}

ul.nav-dropdown li {
  flex: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #DC0644;
  font-family: sans-serif, arial;
  background-color: #333;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.nav-dropdown>li:first-child {
  border-left: 4px solid #DC0644;
}

ul.nav-dropdown>li:last-child {
  border-right: 4px solid #DC0644;
}

ul.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

ul.dropdown-content li {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #DC0644;
  ;
}

ul.dropdown-content li:first-child {
  border-top: 2px solid #DC0644;
}

ul.dropdown-content li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0px solid black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav-dropdown">

    <li class="dropdown"><a id="imperium" href="#imperium">Imperium</a>

      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#sub">Wie zijn wij?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sub1">Vrijwilligers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sub2">Plattegrond</a></li>
      </ul>

    </li>

    <li class="dropdown"><a id="lidworden" href="#lidworden">lid worden</a>

      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#sub">Proces</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sub1">Inschrijfformulier</a></li>
      </ul>

    </li>

    <li class="dropdown"><a id="agenda" href="#agenda">Agenda</a>

      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#sub">Vooruitzicht</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sub1">Archief</a></li>
      </ul>

    </li>

    <li class="dropdown"><a id="gallerij" href="#gallerij">Gallerij</a>

      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#sub">Foto's</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sub1">Video's</a></li>
      </ul>

    </li>

    <li><a id="contact" href="#nieuwsbrief">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a id="nieuwsbrief" href="#nieuwsbrief">Nieuwsbrief</a></li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/63frrrwv/1/

Comment: Is it like this? https://jsfiddle.net/63frrrwv/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work with `position: relative` on the sub-container:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

This doesn't remove the sub-nav from the normal flow, so the entire menu goes down with it on hover.

Instead, use `position: absolute`:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute; /* new */
  width: 100%; /* new */
}
```

AND... remove `overflow: hidden` from the main container:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}
```

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/63frrrwv/3/)